# How would you oscillate values within a closed range in Swift?

Tags: swift

I'm trying to oscillate var aValue: Float with  a few constraints like let range, let frequency, and let step.  range is something like -60...60 that defines lower and upper bound aValue can swing between; frequency is how many cycles it completes in a second; and step is incremental size of the aValue.

Comment: Are you looking for a sine wave parameterised by frequency, amplitude and phase ?

Comment: Yes, that should work for me, too.